# Поиск элемента с ценой больше 100

Tags: jquery

Как мне пропарсить элемент с ID=BETS и достать все числа из data-worth со всех элементов и если моё число больше добавить выше этого элемента мой элемент.
если моё число например больше 100 то добавляем элемент выше или ниже в соответствие с числом

```html
<div id="bets">
  <!-- <div class="bets-content" data-worth="101"></div> допустим моё число 101 добавляем сюда элемент выше всех-->
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="100"></div>
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="89"></div>
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="59"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способов можно много придумать. В любом случае вам потребуется перебрать элементы и найти первый из них, которых подходит под условие. Перед  ним и добавить, а если не нашлось, то добавить в конец.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   var v = +$("input").val();
   
   var $div = $("<div>")
                   .addClass('bets-content')
                   .data('worth', v)
                   .text(v) ;
                   
   $bets = $(".bets-content").filter(function(){
                     return v > +$(this).data('worth');
                }).first();
             
   $bets.length ? $div.insertBefore($bets) : $div.appendTo("#bets");      
});
```

```css
#bets { border:1px solid red; }
.bets-content {border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input/><button>+</button>
<div id="bets">  
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="100">100</div>
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="89">89</div>
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="59">59</div>
</div>
```

Comment: багается почему то, [ссылка](https://pp.userapi.com/c849536/v849536989/159c31/4Yynk9o5wRg.jpg)

Comment: к целым числам потому что не приводились. поправил

Comment: большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на чистом JavaScript.

```js
var b = document.getElementById('bets');
var a = [...b.querySelectorAll('[data-worth]')];
var m = a.find(e => e.dataset.worth > 100);

var d = document.createElement('div');
d.dataset.worth = 123;
b.insertBefore(d, m);
```

```css
[data-worth]::after {
  content: attr(data-worth);
}
```

```html
<div id="bets">
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="38"></div>
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="112"></div>
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="89"></div>
  <div class="bets-content" data-worth="59"></div>
</div>
```